# Remove user and hostname from Gnome Terminal window title?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove user and hostname from Gnome Terminal?

I wish to only see the running command there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do:

0. Open your Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open your `.bashrc` file
2. Find this section:

   ```
   # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
   case "$TERM" in
   xterm*|rxvt*)
       PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
   esac
   ```
3. Remove `\u@\h:`
4. Save the file, and restart Terminal.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!